# C# Click on HtmlElement With no ID only Class

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am not using selenium nor anything else, i just want to do it on the webbrowser on the windows form application.
I have a windows form application and i want to click on a button with code but there is no ID.

[image: Here]

I tried using a lot of different things found on this websites forums, but none of this works.

[image: This is what i work with]

Comment: There's no form in the HTML displayed in your picture of HTML.

Comment: i mean form windows form application sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using WebBrowser.GetElementByTagName("div") and then checking each element against attribute type=submit? 
Your code should look something like

```
HtmlElement submit = FindSubmitElement(webBrowser1.Document);
submit?.InvokeMember("submit");

public HtmlElement FindSubmitElement(HtmlDocument document) 
{
    HtmlElementCollection elems = document.GetElementsByTagName("div"); // since your tag is div
    // this will return collection, even in case there is just one div, find the first one, having an attribute 'type' with value 'submit'
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
    {
        string type = elem.GetAttribute("type");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && type == "submit") 
        {
            return elem; // if div tag with attribute type is found exit and return that html element
        }
    }

    return null; // if no div tags found with an attribute 'type' return null
}
```

Check more on GetElementsByTagName method on the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx). Code is taken from there and adjusted to your need.

Comment: it did not work at first but i changed InvokeMember from submit to click and it worked just fine, thanks :D